# How to write a new line into text file when it finds a special character#{} in shell script

Tags: shell

I want to add a new line into my text file when it finds a special character `"#{}"`.The new line should be added after these special character using shell script .Please help me how to do this.
Foe example let my text file be abc.txt with contents

```
for \n
a bug  \n
"#{}"  \n
to resolve  \n
```

Now i need the script which adds the line after #{}
output should be

```
for  \n
a bug  \n
"#{}"
check and let me know \n - new line added
to resolve   \n
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sed:

```
sed 's/\("#{}"\).*/\1\ncheck and let me know \\n - new line added/' file

for \n
a bug  \n
"#{}"
check and let me know \n - new line added
to resolve  \n
```

Original file:

```
cat file
for \n
a bug  \n
"#{}"  \n
to resolve  \n
```

For just adding newline use:

```
sed 's/\("#{}"\).*/\1\n/' file
```

Comment: when i tried i am getting the below error  sed: Unknown option -i
Usage: sed [-n] script [file...]
       sed [-nE] [-e script] [-f scriptfile] [file...]    please help to resolve

Comment: I didn't even suggest `-i` in my answer. What command you tried and what is your sed version?